# how to apply Font.WeightBold for only one ListBoxitem in ListBox

Tags: xaml, c#-4.0, wpf-controls, wpf-4.0

I am binding listboxitems from an arrayList.This arraylist contains all textbox and combobox text.Now my question is how can i make only one listitem font as bold through code not xaml..because am not adding listbox items from xaml.

any suggestion, idea to implement this..

thanks in advance.

EDIT:

xaml:

```
   <ListBox Name="lstbx"  Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0" BorderBrush="Transparent" > </ListBox>
```

code:

```
    private ArrayList LoadListData()
    {

        ArrayList arrList = new ArrayList();            
        //txtFullName.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold; //this didnt work
        arrList.Add(txtFullName.Text);
        arrList.Add(" ");
    }

     lstbx.ItemsSource=LoadListData();
```

Comment: Please show your current code.

Comment: hi, i updated the code in my question itself...

Comment: I guess this code cant work. Your `LoadListData`does not return anything. It have to return the `ArrayList`. But you could try to do something like `foreach lstbx.Items` and change the FontWeight in this loop. Dont know, just an idea.

Comment: this is not the proper way of playing with listdata . i will give you a basic code example try to follow that.

Comment: @Lucas...sorry i while editing code, forgotto return arraylist in the above code but in actual code am returning arraylist...i'll try and let u know the result

Comment: @tanuj_loop....can u please let me know the how to use list data...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you want but basically I'm filling the listbox with TextBlocks and setting the text content as I want. Just for demonstration:

```
    private void MakeBold()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            TextBlock s = new TextBlock();
            s.Text = "Testing" + i;
            if (i == 3)
                s.FontWeight = FontWeights.Heavy;
            lstbx.Items.Add(s);
        }
    }
```

I get this result:

[image]

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming `txtFullName` is declared programmatically. Even if you set the `FontWeight` programmatically, you are still adding the text only to your list, and the weight information never gets passed along.

Pass the whole `TextBox` instead and it should work:

```
arrList.Add(txtFullName);
```